# In angular-formly, How to use ui-mask in multi-input?

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

In angular formly, I want to apply ui-mask in multiple inputs. How to do that ?

Here is the [multi-input](http://jsbin.com/yuyawo/7/edit)

Here is the [ui-mask](http://jsbin.com/hasosog/6/edit?html,css,js,output)

Any Idea ?

Comment: You just need to overwrite template of the `formly-field` directive and include uiMask directive into new template. There are also template manipulators.